# Migrate PHP app in stages to Angular

Tags: php, node.js, angular

Currently, we have a Multi Page PHP Application and we would like to migrate it in stages to Angular 4. Therefore, we prefer to migrate current modules in stages so we can spread the activities in a couple of months.

Node.js is installed at our localhost testing server, but we’ve a different port (3030) than our XAMPP PHP testing server. Since we would like to replace for example the settings module with an Angular component, we need one url for PHP & Angular. Is it possible to have one URL (http://app.localhost/) for both languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_proxy in your apache (httpd.conf), and then add some proxy_pass for your server

ex <del>something like</del>:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass /module1 https://127.0.0.1:3030/module1
    ProxyPassReverse /module1 https://127.0.0.1:3030/module1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Really nice solution, thank you very much! Works like a charm!